# align an object relatively to another object Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I developed, using `ng-show` and `ng-hide`, a box of description that pops up under a text after I click it. 
But the problem is, the decription box is not shown exactly under the text, like here in the picture[image: picture].

I want the description to be shown exactly under R2A.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>


        <div class="contenu">
          <p>Salut</font><font size="4">, Welcome</font><font size="4">, Bienvenue chez </font><a href="#" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed" style="font-size:180%; color:#B9121B">R2A</a><font size="4">...</font></p>
          <div ><font class="boxed" ng-show="collapsed"size="4" >I am description</font></div>

          <p> Nous sommes ton equipe de Welcomers, nous allons t'accompagner pour ta première journée.</p>
        </div>

</ion-content>
```

**CSS**

```
.collapsed {
width: 300px;
padding: 25px;
border: 25px solid navy;
margin: 25px;
}

.contenu .boxed {
display: inline-block;
  padding:20px; 
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000;
  background-color: #FBC02D; 
}
```

Comment: Could you put the whole HTML code with the container of the text ?

Comment: There is not much in the html code. I added it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, transform the `a` into a `button` and you can put your `boxed` element inside your link.
Now, you can position the `boxed` element relative to the `button` element which contains the R2A text.

The `boxed`element should have the `position: absolute;`, so it positions relative to the first ancestor which does not have the position `static`. Next, the `button`, which by default has the position `static`, should have the `position: relative;`. This means that it positions relative to its default position. If we don't specify `top`, `left` etc. the position remains the same. [More here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

So, the html :

```
 ...
<button class="important-link" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">
    <span>R2A</span>
    <div class="boxed" ng-show="collapsed">
      I am Description
    </div>
  </button> 
 ...
```

And the css:

```
important-link {
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.important-link span {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #B9121B;
}

.boxed {
  min-width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000;
  background-color: #FBC02D;
}
```

And [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/mryu4vy6/) with the whole example.

PS. It's recommended not to use inline CSS in your HTML like `style="font-size:180%; ..`

**Edit**

So, if you don't want some kind of 'tooltip' effect there are two solutions.
In the first one, you add a `margin-top` to the next div, so that the description box doesn't overlap the text below. You can add it with `ng-class` on `ng-style` so the margin applies only if the description box is shown.

Second solution, inside the `button` element, both the text (R2A) and the description should be block elements, so that they position one under the other ([block vs inline elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)).
And then you remove the `position: absolute` from the boxed element (and you can also remove the `position : relative;` from the parent).

Here is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/mryu4vy6/7/).

There are still some limitations in both solutions, so the one you choose depends on the final result. 
You can also use JS to manipulate and position the elements of the DOM.

Comment: there is one thing that bothers me; when i use your solution the boxed elements hide the next text below it. It does not make space for the box to appear between two paragraphs. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just put both of these elements in a separate `div` element and add a break in between `<br>`:

```
<div><a href="#" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed" style="font-size:180%; color:#B9121B">R2A</a>
 <font size="4">...</font></p>
 <br>
 <div>
  <font class="boxed" ng-show="collapsed"size="4" >I am description</font>
 </div>  
</div>
```

Or put them in the same `span`.

You may have to fiddle around with the margins as well.